# If $f_n\rightarrow f$ in $L^2$ and $\lVert f_n\rVert_\infty\le C$ then why is $f\in L^\infty$?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

This exercise from the $L^p$-theory section of my measure theory course is giving me some trouble.

Let $(f_n)_n\subset L^2\cap L^\infty$ be a sequence such that $f_n\rightarrow f\in L^2$ in $L^2$ and $\lVert f_n\rVert_\infty\le C$ for all $n$. I want to show that

1. $f\in L^\infty$ and
2. $f_n\rightarrow f$ in $L^p$ for any $2\le p<\infty$

My most promising attempt at 1. was
$$\lVert f\rVert_\infty=\lVert f-f_n+f_n\rVert_\infty\le \lVert f-f_n\rVert_\infty+C,$$
but how can we bound $\lVert f-f_n\rVert_\infty$?

I'm having similar problems with 2., except of course there we want to bound $\lVert f-f_n\rVert_p$.

Comment: For 1. : assume there is a non-null set $B$ such that on $B$, $f>C+\epsilon$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hints :**

1. Use the fact that because $f_n \rightarrow f$ in $L^2$, then there exists a subsequence $f_{\varphi(n)}$ that converge pointwise almost everywhere to $f$.
2. Use the fact that

$$|f_n-f|^p \leq\left\{
    \begin{array}{ll}
        |f_n-f|^2  & \text{if } |f_n-f|\leq 1\\
        (2C)^p  & \text{if } |f_n-f|^2\geq 1
    \end{array}
\right. $$

Comment: (and the key letters here are DCT!) Nice one, +1

Comment: For 1. just because the subsequence converges pointwise almost everywhere doesn't necessarily mean that $\lVert f-f_n\rVert _\infty\rightarrow 0$, so where is it incorporated into the argument?

Comment: @JustDroppedIn Where is the DCT used?

Comment: @RubenKruepper (1) and (2) are the hypotheses that you must verify before using the dct. after verifying them, use the dct to get your resul

Comment: @JustDroppedIn but how? (2) follows directly if $\lVert f\rVert _\infty\le C$, but as I said in my other comment, I still don't see why this is true just because we can find a pointwise almost everywhere convergent subsequence.

Comment: @RubenKruepper I did not write to use DCT here. For point 1., just notice that $||f_{\varphi(n)}||_{\infty}\leq C$ implies $||f||_{\infty} \leq C$. For point 2., the majoration gives you something like $||f_n-f||_p \leq K ||f_n-f||_2$.

Comment: @RubenKruepper I am not saying that $|f_n-f| \rightarrow 0$ ! Just, once you have $||f_n-f||_p \leq K ||f_n-f||_2$, let $n$ tend to $+\infty$ : because $(f_n)$ tends to $f$ is $L^2$, it gives you directly that $||f_n-f||_p$ tends to $0$.

Comment: Yes sorry, I pulled that comment too late. I meant to say that I don't understand why majoration implies this inequality, when it just allows us to take the limit inside.

Comment: Also, why make a case distinction if you just need the majorization?

Comment: @RubenKruepper If you integrate the inequality, you get 
$$\int |f_n-f|^p d\mu \leq \int_{\lbrace |f_n-f| \leq 1\rbrace} |f_n-f|^2  d\mu + \int_{\lbrace |f_n-f| \geq 1\rbrace} (2C)^p  d\mu \leq ||f_n-f||^2_2 +(2C)^p \mu \lbrace  |f_n-f| \geq 1 \rbrace \leq ||f_n-f||^2_2 +(2C)^p ||f_n-f||^2_2$$
using Markov inequality. So you get $||f_n-f||^p_p \leq (1+(2C)^p)||f_n-f||^2_2$, and you are done. The case distinction is necessary, because you cannot majorate directly $|f_n-f|^p$ by $|f_n-f|^2$ if $|f_n-f| \geq 1$.

Answer (score 2):

1. Use that the set $\{f\in L^2: \ |f|\le M \ a.e.\}$ is closed (use pointwise convergent subsequences).
2. Follows from $\|f\|_{L^p}^p \le \|f\|_{L^2}^{2} \|f\|_{L^\infty}^{p-2}$:
   $$
   \int |f|^p dx \le \|f\|_{L^\infty}^{p-2} \int |f|^2 dx.
   $$

Comment: whats wrong with the answer?

Comment: +1. I don't see anything wrong with the answer. Perhaps the fact that $f$ is a special function in the question and a generic function in the answer led to downvoting.